# How can I use the .Select(T, index) overload in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to do this:

```
list.Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
```

But in the LINQ query syntax, something like:

```
from x  in list
select(x, i) { Item = x, Index = i }
```

But that doesn't work. Or maybe there is another way to increment en scoped variable in the LINQ query?

Comment: The index of the element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no form of C# query expression which uses that overload. Basically you *have* to do it as an extension method call to use that overload.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
var q = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
        select new
        {
            Item = list[i],
            Index = i
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of Select that use an integer as argument of the "lambda" expression.

Comment: You mean the one in the question? I think the OP knows about that.

Answer (score -1):

```
        int index = 0;
        var r = list.Select(p => new {Item = p, Index = index++ }).ToList();
```

Comment: "But in the LINQ query syntax, something like:"  This isn't what the OP is looking for.